# Stop priniting the Accurancy while cross validation in SVM in LIBSVM

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

I am using cross validation in svmtrain in LIBSVM. How can I make it stop printing the "Cross Validation Accuracy" in the consol?
Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww It is about programming though. He has to change the source code in order to do this

Comment: @Pedrom - you should nominate for reopen.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change the code for that because there is not option to do cross-validation in silent mode.

You didn't specified how you are using libsvm so assuming that you are in C, this is the function you must to change:

```
void do_cross_validation()
{
    int i;
    int total_correct = 0;
    double total_error = 0;
    double sumv = 0, sumy = 0, sumvv = 0, sumyy = 0, sumvy = 0;
    double *target = Malloc(double,prob.l);

    svm_cross_validation(&prob,&param,nr_fold,target);
    if(param.svm_type == EPSILON_SVR ||
       param.svm_type == NU_SVR)
    {
        for(i=0;i<prob.l;i++)
        {
            double y = prob.y[i];
            double v = target[i];
            total_error += (v-y)*(v-y);
            sumv += v;
            sumy += y;
            sumvv += v*v;
            sumyy += y*y;
            sumvy += v*y;
        }
        printf("Cross Validation Mean squared error = %g\n",total_error/prob.l);
        printf("Cross Validation Squared correlation coefficient = %g\n",
            ((prob.l*sumvy-sumv*sumy)*(prob.l*sumvy-sumv*sumy))/
            ((prob.l*sumvv-sumv*sumv)*(prob.l*sumyy-sumy*sumy))
            );
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<prob.l;i++)
            if(target[i] == prob.y[i])
                ++total_correct;
        printf("Cross Validation Accuracy = %g%%\n",100.0*total_correct/prob.l);
    }
    free(target);
}
```

EDIT: This you just told me that you are using matlab, you will need to remove the mexPrintf statement from svmtrain.c:100 and recompile the interface within Matlab.

Comment: I am using in matlab by using this line                      cv_acc(i) = svmtrain(labels, data,sprintf('-t 2  -c %f -g %f -v %d  ', 2^C(i), 2^gamma(i), folds));
end          .Cross validation is done automatically by adding -v and variable fold which specify the number of validation folds.

Comment: @user3656367 Then I think you would need to make the changes on the C code and recompile the matlab interface

Comment: Yes the changes must be done in the C file.simply commenting the print command.